# Error converting large size image to base64 string cordova android

Tags: android, image, cordova, base64, filereader

I am implementing some functionality in my hybrid app where I am capturing image from camera using cordova api. I get the path of image, which I convert to base64 for uploading to some server. I used file reader api's readAsDataURL method to convert local image path to base64. Everything works fine until the image size exceeds some particular limit in this case it fails for more than 2MB size images. I get following error in my logcat

> Refusing to load URL as it exceeds 2097152 characters

which is I think my base64 string which is large. Can anybody give me some idea how to overcome this issue.

Comment: what plugin are you using for image capture?

Comment: Use Blobs instead. The File object is a blob itself - send this to server.